# bottom bar div is not adjust at bellow in html and css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hi guys I Developed a reactjs application where a user can post their products the problem is that i have bottom bar div from top 160vh and position is fixed and I must show 5 products on the page and below its I showed bottom bar when description of products is sufficient then there is no issue and when I have long description then my bottom bar component is shown up and products showing its below , how to show it always below the five products and also in different pages bottom bar component how to show always below. my code of css is

bottom bar container

```
.bottom-bar-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(194, 188, 188);
  position: absolute;
  top: 160vh;
  height: 25vh;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}
```

and app-container where i render all products

```````
.app-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
``````
how to show always it below 
i also attached image of my app plz see it.


  https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1aPd.png
```````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like your footer to stay at the bottom of your page, try using the `absolute` value for the `position` property. Here is how you would use that in your code...

```
.app-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 70px;
  
  /* New code */
  position: relative;
}

.bottom-bar-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(194, 188, 188);
  height: 25vh;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  
  /* New code */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you wanna show it always below, then user `bottom:0` instead of `top:160vh`
- Make the parent component's position relative like:-

```
.app-container{
     position:relative;
 }
```